# Handling duplicate email address in django allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to avoid duplicate email address by following these steps:

1. Before user login to my site from a social account I check to see if the email address already exists.
2. If no then login the user otherwise check the below steps.

   - Check to see if the provider of registered user match the user trying to login.
   - If no then don't allow user to login otherwise login the user.

**What is the problem ?**

I get the following error:

***Error:***`AttributeError at /accounts/twitter/login/callback/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'profile'`

**My Code:**

***views.py:***

```
@receiver(pre_social_login)
def handleDuplicateEmail(sender, request, sociallogin, **kwargs):
    if sociallogin.account.provider == 'facebook' or sociallogin.account.provider == 'twitter': 
        email_address = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email'] # get email address from fb or twitter social account.
    else:
        email_address = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email-address']  # Get email from linkedin social account.
    users = User.objects.all().filter(email=email_address) # This line is problematic
    if users:  
        if not (users.profile.provider == sociallogin.account.provider):    # Different user is trying to login with already existing user's email address.         
            response = 'Your social account email address is already registered to some account. Please choose a different one.'
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(render(request, 'index.html', {'type': True, 'response': response}))    # redirect to index template with error message.
```

***models.py:***

```
class Profile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)        
     provider = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True) # for storing name of provider used to login with.
```

***Edit:***

Since *Facebook*, *Twitter* and *Linkedin* give users a choice to login with their phone number or email address and if they choose phone number then in that cause users won't have an email address associated with them to handle this situation I have updated my code like so:

```
if sociallogin.account.provider == 'facebook' or sociallogin.account.provider == 'twitter': 
    try:
        email_address = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email']
    except:
        email_address = None # If social account was created on phone number for facebook & twitter
else:
    try:
        email_address = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email-address'] 
    except:
        email_address = None # If social account was created on phone number or linkedin
if email_address:        
    users = User.objects.all().filter(email=email_address)
    if users.exists():
        ...
else:
    response = 'You have not provided an email address in your social account. Please register as local user or use a different social account.'
    raise ImmediateHttpResponse(render(request, 'index.html', {'type': True, 'response': response}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`users = User.objects.all().filter(email=email_address)` returns a `QuerySet` so you can't just call `.profile` on it. In theory this query could return multiple `User` objects. But it could also contain 0 objects (which is more likely).

So you need to handle these cases:

```
if users.exists():
    user = users.first()  # assuming there will always only be one user
    if not user.profile.provider == sociallogin.account.provider:
        etc...
```

or

```
if users.exists():
    for user in users:
         if not user.profile.provider == sociallogin.account.provider:
             etc...
             break
```

Comment: Thanks it works :). Btw I would like to know if that is the right way to handle duplicate email address ? and is there any way i could simply get the provider of registered user instead of explicitly storing it in profile model. ?

Comment: I have encountered yet another problem. If the username of duplicate email holders don't match then my code fails. In simply terms username of duplicate email must also match otherwise i get an empty `<QuerySet []>` how would I fix this problem ?

Comment: Problem solved. It seems linkedin does not convert the email address to lower case. so I had to convert the email address to lower case. So is this the right way to handle duplicate emails ?

Comment: @Ahtisham I'm a little bit puzzled. I also use django-allauth and don't have to write anything to check for duplicate emails, that's automatically handled by django-allauth. If you set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True`, there will be an extra signup step using the `allauth.socicalaccount.forms.SignupForm` to prompt the user for an email address if he hasn't provided it via _linkedin_. And it'll check unique emails.