# How should I safely add an entry to a database for my Django website without a user entering any data?

Tags: python, django, rest, spotipy

I am building a website using Django and Spotipy. When a new user enters the website, they press a button and are redirected to Spotify's login page to authorize the website. I would like to use the get_or_create() method to create a new entry in my database for that Spotify user if one does not already exist. However, the Django documentation says to use get_or_create() only in POST requests. The issue is that after authorizing my website on the Spotify page, you are directed to a callback view where the request method is GET.

How would I go about creating a POST request in the callback view so I can safely add the user?
Alternatively, is it bad practice to add to a database on a callback page? If so, when and how would you reccommend I add the users information?

I considered using get() and create() separately but I imagine anytime create() is used should be in a POST request. After doing some reading, it also seems that it may be possible to use pythons request library, but this seems like it would be unnecessary.

Comment: Check allauth library that is designed for third party singup and login

Comment: You can use this as simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243875/handling-duplicate-email-address-in-django-allauth django allauth supports for spotify as well.

Comment: It’s not a hard rule that it must be a POST request. The documentation says “unless you have a good reason.” External authentication is a good reason because they usually do a GET request to your site after logging in. The idea of the warning is just that a regular GET should not affect changes to the system usually and this is true to any framework and system. There still are exceptions.